# Bundle HTML project into one single HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I have a static HTML report in the following structure

```
1.css
2.font
3.js
4.pages
5.attachments
6.index.html
```

How can I bundle all these to generate a single report.html?

Comment: If you know html and javascript this should not be to complicated, but might be a better way to solve this? Create reports in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/chyingp/grunt-inline

However, you may need some additional trickery depending on what is inside /pages and /attachments folders

Comment: Hi, attachments folder contain .png images and pages folder conatiain .html files

Comment: well, if it is a multi-page site (multiple HTML pages loaded depending on user actions), you may have to refactor the whole thing manually.